# Update value from multiple checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

What I basicaly want to do is this: click on the checkbox and update the total value which is $5000. So if I click the two, it will be $5110, and if I uncheck the $60 for instance, it will drop to $5050.

[image].

I couldn't past the whole progress of my code, so I included it in my webpage in a css file: http://adroid.cl/js_problem.css.

I almost got this code done, but it has some bugs, and I would really appreciate I receive some guidance on this one, thank you!

Comment: In fact your CSS file is not correct. It should contain only CSS rules but **not** the whole code including markup and JavaScript.

Comment: @VisioN , i think he's saved it as a css file so it loads the source of the webpage he's not actually planning on linking it in his webpage  and Herland next time just create a jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Yusaf it really worked, thank you! I updated your code to give it currency format, that was my last difficulty. http://jsfiddle.net/3n6Xu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### http://jsfiddle.net/zmJ3k/

with no html included you will have to change some attributes

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var total = document.getElementById("total");
for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
    input[i].onchange = function(){
        if(this.checked){
             total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + parseFloat(this.value);
        }else{
             total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) - parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/zmJ3k/1/

forgot about the $

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var total = document.getElementById("total");
for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
    input[i].onchange = function(){
        if(this.checked){
             total.innerHTML = "$" + (parseFloat(total.innerHTML.split("$")[1]) + parseFloat(this.value));
        }else{
             total.innerHTML = "$" + (parseFloat(total.innerHTML.split("$")[1]) - parseFloat(this.value));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oops, just looked at your jquery file, but d.w it will work as normal

Comment: Thank you so much @Yusaf Khaliq it does update the price value. But I am having another difficulty, that is the currency format. I'm trying to add this format: 5.000 or 49.000 but I don't know where in the Javascript to add this function. I add `total.formatMoney(0,'.',',')` but it doesn't work

Comment: sorry that makes no sense to me